# SQL: Composite primary key as foreign key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a database in postgres about NY counties on their education aid amount and criminality rates ranging from 2010 to 2019, these are the two tables

```
CREATE TABLE NYAidCrimeTimeSeries 
(
    County VARCHAR(50),
    Year int,
    AidAmount int,
    Population int,
    JailPopulation int,
    CrimesReported int,
    PRIMARY KEY (County, year)
)

CREATE TABLE NYAidCrimeMean 
(
    County VARCHAR(50),
    AidAmount_mean int,
    Population_mean int,
    JailPopulation_mean int,
    CrimesReported_mean int,
    AidPerCap int,
    CrimesPerCap int,

    FOREIGN KEY (County) REFERENCES nyaidcrimetimeseries (County)
)
```

Would this be possible? Having a composite primary key as a foreign key? If not, what direction should I go try?

Comment: You should be using both county and year for the foreign key reference.

Comment: Since the second table cant use the year, should I just create a unique index for county or for each entry?

Comment: Since `County` is a prefix of the composite key, it can be used as a key by itself as well.

Comment: I think what you've written should work because of that. I think MySQL allows FK to non-unique keys.

Comment: Your code is legal formally (except the letters case difference which may be critical depends on server settings). Really - if `County` is not defined as UNIQUE  (it is not now) then your relation is ambiguous, you can use this relation for to check that the value in 2nd table exists in 1st table, but you cannot define what row it is related onto. Also you cannot use cascade operations correctly.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I messed up the post, I'm actually using postgres, would it still work? And is it good database design? If not what would be the alternative

Comment: @Akina what would be a good solution since it might be legal but not actually recommended?

Comment: @robotcourier I think your FK is reversed. You should point `NYAidCrimeTimeSeries` to `NYAidCrimeMean`, since the relationship is N:1.

Comment: @TheImpaler so would PRIMARY KEY (County, year), FOREIGN KEY (County) REFERENCES NYAidCrimeMean (County) work? Is many to one considered good design?

Comment: *what would be a good solution since it might be legal but not actually recommended?* Does `County` must be UNIQUE by the meaning? If true then create according UNIQUE index. If not then the situation looks as unsolvable.

Comment: @robotcourier You can [check it by yourself](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4db55ece5fbeed75558a4d0444285d54): it does not work. Also it is not a good design: you need some reference dataset to check against and the column(s) should be identifying (because subset of key can be meaningless)

Comment: The problem with reversing the relationship is that it doesn't make sense to calculate a mean if there aren't any per-year statistics. What may be wanted is a `Counties` table that both tables reference as a FK, plust a `CHECK` constraint in the `NYAidCrimeMean` that there's at least one corresponding row in `NYAidCrimeTimeSeries`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of a foreign key is to guarantee that one or more keys in one table have a corresponding row in another table.  The "a" in this context is *singular*.  And, in general, foreign keys should be using primary keys.  Any unique key is allowed, but primary keys are strongly recommended.

Your data model is just begging for a `counties` table.  At the very least:

```
create table counties (
     county_id int generated always as identity primary key,
     name varchar(255)
);
```

The `county_id` can then be a foreign key in both the other tables.  Well, in fact, perhaps the summary statistics could also be columns in `counties`.

Hmmmm . . . It is possible that you just have the foreign key definitions in the wrong place.  You want `county` to be the primary key of `NYAidCrimeMean` and then for `NYAidCrimeTimeSeries` to reference that table.

If you do take this approach, I would suggest renaming `NYAidCrimeMean` because the table name does not suggest that it is one row per county.  At least to those not familiar with your domain.

Comment: I think what you proposed last was the issue, now its PRIMARY KEY (County, year), FOREIGN KEY (County) REFERENCES NYAidCrimeMean (County). But Barmar mentioned in the last comment it might not work out, should I just create the table counties?

Comment: @robotcourier . . . It will work if `NYAidCrimeMean` has exactly one row per county.

Comment: it does, thank you! I was mostly worried about it being overall good database design